# Determining when two finite abelian groups are isomorphic

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

What is the most efficient algorithm to tell when two finite abelian groups are isomorphic. How does this relate to invariant factor forms and primary normal forms? I am having trouble understanding how these all relate.

Comment: How are your two groups given, as an input of your algorithm?

Comment: I dont have an algorithm. The groups are given as a product of finite abelian groups, ie Zn1 x Zn2 x ...

Comment: So your input is just two sequences of integers? The easiest way with numbers that are not too big is to factorize all of the $n_i$ into prime powers, and then just compare the sequences of prime powers $p^k$ for each prime $p$ dividing the group order. But for very large integers factorizing into primes is difficult computationally, and a more efficient algorithm would be to compute the invariant factors of the two groups using $\gcd$ computations.